# Read and write sdcard simultaneosly

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

I am having a test-case, as a part of it I need to show two Progress bars Simultaneously on UI using threads.Is it possible,if possible any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two thread for showing two progress bar like following

```
final ProgressBar p1 = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    final ProgressBar p2 = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    p1.setMax(20);
    p2.setMax(20);
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                Looper.prepare();
                while(seconds1 > 0) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    seconds1--;

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                       @Override 
                       public void run() { 
                           p1.setProgress(seconds1);


                       } 
                   });

                }

            } catch ( InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                Looper.prepare();
                while(seconds2 < 20) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    seconds2++;

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                       @Override 
                       public void run() { 
                           p2.setProgress(seconds2);


                       } 
                   });

                }

            } catch ( InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread2.start();
```